# transformation a certain number of elements

Tags: python, function, numpy

I am using this but I find it very inelegant. Any improvements are very welcomed:

```
import numpy as np 
def getCoordinate(lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2):
    lat1 = np.radians(lat1)
    lat2 = np.radians(lat2)
    lon1 = np.radians(lon1)
    lon2 = np.radians(lon2)
#......
#Use them in the rest of the function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have `np.radians()` convert all values as a sequence and use iterable assignment to unpack the results again:

```
lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2 = np.radians((lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2))
```

Comment: Why the map? np.radians can handle the tuple, no?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I never have cause to use numpy, so I translated the OP code directly to a `map()` call without checking if the function can handle a sequence as well as individual values. Indeed, `np.radians` supports a sequency all by itself. I'll update.